# Create a Tree like Category Column in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, tree

In a custom list, is there any way to create a column that will act like a tree?

**For example:**

Categories
Categories => Electronics
Categories => Electronics => Mobile Phones
Categories => Electronics => Mobile Phones => Smart Phones
Categories => Electronics => Mobile Phones => Dummy Phones
Categories => Electronics => Computers
Categories => Electronics => Computers => Hardware
Categories => Electronics => Computers => Software
Categories => Instruments
Categories => Instruments => Keyboards
Categories => Instruments => Guitars
Categories => Instruments => Guitars => Bass Guitars

As you can see, the will all include data from itself.

To understand the usage, you can think of this data to be used for category in an ebay like application to sell an item.

I tried to use lookup to itself(its title in this case) but that was not exactly the solution I was looking for, because it didn't gave me a default way of use to drilldown the categories.

*Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box you can use the [Managed Metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee559337.aspx) column type. Otherwise, you will need a custom field type to provide that kind of behavior.